# Web workers support

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Does Web worker support?

1. XMLHttpRequest and Call back
2. File upload
3. Websockets

I found very confusing answers in different sites.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: I know you've just now reached the threshold for being able to accept answers, but let me know if you need more here

Comment: Ya pls, help me with regard to usage of web sockets in web workers.. I am clear with XHR and callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, test it out. My version of Chromium suggests the answers are:

- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest): Yes
- [File upload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications): Yes
- [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets): Yes

Source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/Rtmct/) and below.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Embedded Web Worker Test</title>
<script type="text/js-worker">
  var xmlhttp = 'XMLHttpRequest: ' + ( ( 'function' === typeof XMLHttpRequest ) ? ' YES' : ' NO' )
  var file_reader = 'FileReader: ' + ( ( 'function' === typeof FileReader ) ? ' YES' : ' NO' )
  var websockets = 'Websockets: ' + ( ( 'function' === typeof WebSocket ) ? ' YES' : ' NO' )    
    var myVar = "Test results: " + xmlhttp + ", " + file_reader + ", " + websockets;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function log_worker_msg(worker_msg) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(worker_msg));
    document.querySelector("#worker_log").appendChild(frag);
  }
</script>
<script type="text/js-worker">
  self.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
    self.postMessage(myVar);
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var oBuilder = new WebKitBlobBuilder() || new MozBlobBuilder();
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("script[type=\"text\/js-worker\"]"), function (oScript) { oBuilder.append(oScript.textContent); });

  var obj_url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(oBuilder.getBlob()) || window.URL.createObjectURL(oBuilder.getBlob());
  document.worker = new Worker(obj_url);

  document.worker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
    log_worker_msg( oEvent.data);
  };

  window.onload = function() { document.worker.postMessage(""); };
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="worker_log"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: If my answer suits your needs, please mark it as "Correct." Else, let me know what more I can do to help

Comment: I am using Firefox 13 and it shows the following error: WebKitBlobBuilder is not defined

Comment: When I open in opera 11.64 , the error is "Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: WebKitBlobBuilder"

Comment: Yes, those are vendor prefixed APIs. For Firefox change  `WebKitBlobBuilder()` to `MozBlobBuilder()`. Not sure whether Opera supports document blobs (which are used here to build the Web Worker).

Comment: We already have MozBlobBuilder() , so I removed WEbKitBlobBuilder(). Here , window.webkitURL.createObjectURL, again we have webkit which throws 
window.webkitURL is undefined error

Comment: Yes, as I said I wrote it with Chrome in mind only throwing in those prefixes (untested) for good measure. Does my response answer your question? If so please mark as correct or let me know how I can improve upon it.

Comment: Well, I made some tweaks in code to make it work.   
var oBuilder = ( window.WebKitBlobBuilder || new window.MozBlobBuilder); This line makes it work in the firefox, I have to prefix window keyword and remove new . 
var oBuilder = new WebKitBlobBuilder() || new MozBlobBuilder();
The above lines work in chrome. I am unable to run the pgm in safari and opera.Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Your webworker support test contains significant errors, which results in worker throwing reference errors.
BlobBuilder is deprecated, Blob is preferably used browserwide, however it is not widely supported yet.

[Blob support](http://caniuse.com/blobbuilder)

I have corrected the embedded worker test for sake of testing it's support against 
XMLHttpRequest
File upload
Websockets

The corrected source is here.
[corrected source](http://jsfiddle.net/zludany/nG3nx/)

```
function log_worker_msg(worker_msg) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(worker_msg));
  document.querySelector("#worker_log").appendChild(frag);
}
var aFileParts = ["var xmlhttp = \'XMLHttpRequest: \' + ( ( \'function\' === typeof XMLHttpRequest ) ? \' YES\' : \' NO\' );var file_reader = 'FileReader: ' + ( ( \'function\' === typeof FileReader ) ? \' YES\' : \' NO\' );var websockets = \'Websockets: \' + ( ( \'function\' === typeof WebSocket ) ? \' YES\' : \' NO\' );var myVar = \"Test results: \" + xmlhttp + \", \" + file_reader + \", \" + websockets;self.onmessage=function(oEvent){self.postMessage(myVar)};"];
var oBuilder = new Blob(aFileParts, { "type" : "text\/javascript" });
var obj_url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(oBuilder) || window.URL.createObjectURL(oBuilder);
document.worker = new Worker(obj_url);
document.worker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
    log_worker_msg( oEvent.data);
};
window.onload = function() { document.worker.postMessage(""); };
```